# What is the electric potential of each of the 2 points of an alternating current source?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, potential, voltage

I have that question.
I am **not** asking about the voltage or electric potential **difference**.
I guess the answer will depend on what type of generator is used in the power plant: maybe synchronous. Can the potential of each of the 2 points be a function of time?
I know you have the answer.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sure since the difference in potentials is a function of time the potentials must change. However we have no way to measure it because what is absolute 0 potential?

Answer (score 0):

> I am not asking about the voltage or electric potential difference.

There is no absolute reference for electric potential, so only potential differences are measurable and physically meaningful.

You can't ask about the electric potential without defining some point to have a potential of 0 and then determining the potential difference relative to that point.

> Can the potential of each of the 2 points be a function of time?

If you are talking about an alternating current (AC) source, then by definition at least one of the conductors has a potential that varies as a function of time.